# Java 2d rotation in direction mouse point

Tags: java, rotation, 2d, image-rotation

So far I have a java app where I draw a circle(player) and then draw a green rectangle on top(gun barrel). I have it so when the player moves, the barrel follows with it. I want it to find where the mouse is pointing and then rotate the barrel accordingly. For an example of what I mean look at this video I found http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8W7WSkQq5SU See how the player image reacts when he moves the mouse around?

Here's an image of what the game looks like so far:

[image: My Progress]

So how do I rotate it like this? Btw I don't like using affinetransform or Graphics2D rotation. I was hoping for a better way. Thanks

Comment: *Btw I don't like using affinetransform or Graphics2D rotation* good luck then :P - In java about the only way to do what you want with any level of efficiency is via `Affinetransform` or `Graphics2D.rotate`, unless you want to "manually" adjust the pixels your self, then I hardly think that meets *a better way* criteria

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the `Graphics2D` rotation method is indeed the easiest way. Here's a simple implementation:

```
int centerX = width / 2;
int centerY = height / 2;
double angle = Math.atan2(centerY - mouseY, centerX - mouseX) - Math.PI / 2;

((Graphics2D)g).rotate(angle, centerX, centerY);

g.fillRect(...); // draw your rectangle
```

If you want to remove the rotation when you're done so you can continue drawing normally, use:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
AffineTransform transform = g2d.getTransform();

g2d.rotate(angle, centerX, centerY);

g2d.fillRect(...); // draw your rectangle

g2d.setTransform(transform);
```

It's a good idea to just use `Graphics2D` anyway for anti-aliasing, etc.

Comment: awesome thank you for the simple code! didn't know it was that easier wow!

Answer (score 3):

Using `AffineTransform`, sorry, only way I know how :P

```
public class RotatePane extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private BufferedImage img;
    private Point mousePoint;

    /**
     * Creates new form RotatePane
     */
    public RotatePane() {

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/MT02.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

                mousePoint = e.getPoint();

                repaint();

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

        return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        double rotation = 0f;

        int width = getWidth() - 1;
        int height = getHeight() - 1;

        if (mousePoint != null) {

            int x = width / 2;
            int y = height / 2;

            int deltaX = mousePoint.x - x;
            int deltaY = mousePoint.y - y;

            rotation = -Math.atan2(deltaX, deltaY);

            rotation = Math.toDegrees(rotation) + 180;

        }

        int x  = (width - img.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y  = (height - img.getHeight()) / 2;

        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotation), width / 2, height / 2);
        g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);

        x = width / 2;
        y = height / 2;
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, y - height / 4);
        g2d.dispose();

    }
}
```

Will produce this effect

[image: Rotating]

The red line (point out from the center) will want to follow the cursor.