# Read an Image in Java and perform Affine Transforms

Tags: java, image-processing, affinetransform, getpixel

So for a class project, I have to read an `Image` file and perform`Affine Transforms` on it.  I found how to do the format using information which is present in the Complete Reference bool using the `PixelGrabber` class. However, I have to do this for a number of images.

In the `Affine Transforms`class, how do I give the image as an input. It does not accept a 2d array as the input. How exactly in input to be given in this case? I have to obtain an image's `reflection`, `rotation` and`scaled up` form and save them.

Comment: My understanding of AffoneTransform is its suppose to be applied agonats a Graphics context, you could check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824684/change-the-angle-position-of-a-drawing-with-a-algorithm-in-java/12826882#12826882) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911316/java-2d-rotation-in-direction-mouse-point/11911470#11911470) as examples

Comment: Wow, that was some awesome typing on my part. That's what you get for trying to answer a question with an iPad in one had an 6 month old in the other :P