# Image rotates wrong direction with Graphics2D.rotate()

Tags: java, image, rotation

My goal is to have an image face wherever the mouse cursor is, here is my code for obtaining the rotation angle (within my Ship class) :

```
public void reOrient() {
    Point m = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    // getBoard().getPanel() is the JPanel on which the image will be drawn
    Point c = getBoard().getPanel().getLocationOnScreen();
    int x = m.x - c.x, y = m.y - c.y;
    float angle = (float) (Math.atan2(getY() - y, x - getX()));
    setOrientation(angle);

}
```

Then within my paint method on my JPanel :

```
AffineTransform reset = new AffineTransform();
    reset.rotate(0, 0, 0);
    g2d.rotate(ship.getOrientation(), ship.getX() + 26,
            ship.getY() + 26);
    g2d.drawImage(ship.getImage(), ship.getX(), ship.getY(), this);
    g2d.setTransform(reset);
```

My issue is that when I move my mouse counterclockwise the image rotates clockwise...any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried inverting the angle?  Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911316/java-2d-rotation-in-direction-mouse-point/11911470#11911470)

Comment: Yeah I already tried that and it worked but seeing as I have a lot of rotating images in my program I'd like to be able to understand why my original code doesn't work so I'm not just fiddling with things until they work

Comment: Two things I can see different, 1- You seem to missing ` - Math.PI / 2` from your angle calculation (`double angle = Math.atan2(centerY - mouseY, centerX - mouseX) - Math.PI / 2;` and 2- You're not inverting the result `g2d.rotate(-ship.getOrientation(), ship.getX() + 26, ship.getY() + 26);`

Comment: I now have `float angle = (float) -(Math.atan2(getY() - y, x - getX()));` and it works fine, my question is why do I need to invert the angle?

Comment: I would say it has to do with how `AffineTransformation` treats the angles.  For example.  With some of methods in the `Graphics` API start 0 at the right hand side and move counter counter clockwise, some start at the top and move clockwise...I think they just like keeping us on our feet ;)