# Setting arc position in Java using Mouse

Tags: java, graphics, mouse, paintcomponent, pane

I am writing a 2D program. On my `paintComponent` I created an arc.

```
public class Board extends Panel{

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;//set mouses current position
        int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;

        graphics2d.setStroke(wideStroke);
        graphics2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(200, 200, 100, 100, ?, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));

    }
}
```

In my main I am using a `Thread` to update the graph. The position of the `?` is the starting angle. Every time I change this the arc will move in a circle like half a car wheel. Is it possible to get the arc movement to follow the mouse? e.g. `? = 270`

[image]

How will I do this? (Sorry for my bad paint skills!)

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911316/java-2d-rotation-in-direction-mouse-point/11911470#11911470) FYI- MouseInfo us not really a good choice, MouseMotionListener is probably a better choice

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Changing it to a MouseMotionListener is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the information from [Java 2d rotation in direction mouse point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911316/java-2d-rotation-in-direction-mouse-point/11911470#11911470)

We need two things.  We need the anchor point (which would be the centre point of the arc) and the target point, which would be the mouse point.

Using a `MouseMotionListener`, its possible to monitor the mouse movements within the component

```
// Reference to the last known position of the mouse...
private Point mousePoint;
//....
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mousePoint = e.getPoint();                    
        repaint();                    
    }                
});
```

Next we need to calculate the angle between these two points...

```
if (mousePoint != null) {
    // This represents the anchor point, in this case, 
    // the centre of the component...
    int x = width / 2;
    int y = height / 2;

    // This is the difference between the anchor point
    // and the mouse.  Its important that this is done
    // within the local coordinate space of the component,
    // this means either the MouseMotionListener needs to
    // be registered to the component itself (preferably)
    // or the mouse coordinates need to be converted into
    // local coordinate space
    int deltaX = mousePoint.x - x;
    int deltaY = mousePoint.y - y;

    // Calculate the angle...
    // This is our "0" or start angle..
    rotation = -Math.atan2(deltaX, deltaY);
    rotation = Math.toDegrees(rotation) + 180;
}
```

From here, you would need to subtract 90 degrees, which would give your arcs start angle and then use an extent of 180 degrees.

Comment: I understand what you are showing me in this code. The only problem I have is how will I get the arch to rotate with the mouse?

Comment: MouseMotionListener maintains the last mouse position,, calling repaint, which calculates the angle and draws the arc. See the linked example for a runnable example

Comment: Thank you this should help.