# Failed to implement object rotation towards mouse JAVA

Tags: java, swing, rotation, mouselistener

As title say, just can't do it. Attempted for long time and still fail. (I'm new to java)
My Image or fillRect rotate a little bit but not as it should rotate

Whole code +imgs

```
    *MAIN game class*
    package game.main;

    import java.awt.Canvas;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

    public class game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -392333887196083915L;

        public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
        private Thread thread;
        private boolean running = false;

        private Handler handler;

        public game(){

            handler = new Handler();

            new window(WIDTH, HEIGHT,"Game",this);

            handler.addObject(new Player(WIDTH/2-32, HEIGHT/2-32, ID.Player, handler));
        }

        public synchronized void start(){
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
            running = true;
        }
        public synchronized void stop(){
            try{
                thread.join();
                running = false;
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // ↓ game loop for update
        public void run(){
            this.requestFocus();
            long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
            double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
            double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
            double delta = 0;
            long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int frames = 0;
            while(running){
                long now = System.nanoTime();
                delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
                lastTime = now;
                while(delta >= 1){
                    tick();
                    delta--;
                }
                if(running)
                    render();
                frames++;

                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                    timer += 1000;
                    System.out.print("FPS:" + frames);
                    frames = 0;
                }
            }
            stop();
        }

        private void tick(){
                    handler.tick();             
                }

        private void render(){
            BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
            if(bs == null){
                this.createBufferStrategy(3);
                return;
            }

            Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

            handler.render(g);

            g.dispose();
            bs.show();
        }



        public static void main(String args[]) {
            new game();
        }


    }
<br>
package game.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public abstract class GameObject {

    protected float x, y;
    protected ID id;
    protected float velX, velY;

    public GameObject(float x, float y, ID id){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.id = id;
    }

    public abstract void tick();
    public abstract void render(Graphics g);

    public void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }   
    public float getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public float getY(){
        return y;
    }
    public void setId(ID id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public ID getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setVelX(int velX){
        this.velX = velX;
    }
    public void setVelY(int velY){
        this.velY = velY;
    }
    public float getVelX(){
        return velX;
    }
    public float getVelY(){
        return velY;
    }
}
```

```
*GameObject class*
package game.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public abstract class GameObject {

    protected float x, y;
    protected ID id;
    protected float velX, velY;

    public GameObject(float x, float y, ID id){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.id = id;
    }

    public abstract void tick();
    public abstract void render(Graphics g);

    public void setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }   
    public float getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public float getY(){
        return y;
    }
    public void setId(ID id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public ID getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setVelX(int velX){
        this.velX = velX;
    }
    public void setVelY(int velY){
        this.velY = velY;
    }
    public float getVelX(){
        return velX;
    }
    public float getVelY(){
        return velY;
    }
}
```

```
*Handler class*
package game.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;

// render all objects
public class Handler {

    LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();

    public void tick(){
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.tick();      
        }
    }
    public void render(Graphics g){
        for(int i = 0; i <object.size();i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.render(g);
        }
    }// handling adding objects
    public void addObject(GameObject object){
        this.object.add(object);
    }   
}
```

```
*window class*
package game.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class window extends Canvas{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3010486623466540351L;

    public window(int width, int height, String title, game game){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        // X button
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // ¤ button maximize
        frame.setResizable(false);
        // window appear in middle of screen instead of top left corner
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // add game to window
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }       
}
```

```
* ID class*
package game.main;

public enum ID {

    Player();
}
```

ADDED code only to this class

```
*Player class*
package game.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;

public class Player extends GameObject{

    Handler handler;

    public Player(int x, int y, ID id, Handler handler) {
        super(x, y, id);
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void tick() {
    }
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        ///////////ADDED//////////////////
        PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point b = a.getLocation();
        int mouseX = (int) b.getX();
        int mouseY = (int) b.getY();
        int centerX = game.WIDTH / 2;
        int centerY = game.HEIGHT / 2;
        double angle = Math.atan2(centerY - mouseY, centerX - mouseX) - Math.PI / 2;
        ((Graphics2D)g).rotate(angle, centerX, centerY);
        //////////////////////////////
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, 32, 32);

    }
}
```

How it now works and how I want it. WHITE COLOR - original/ GREEN - I want it like that
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfGpD.jpg)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2gQZ.jpg)

I looked in this sources:
[Get mouse possition (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439022/get-mouse-position)
[Java 2d rotation in direction mouse point (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911316/java-2d-rotation-in-direction-mouse-point/11911470#11911470?newreg=cb396c8955584c5eb31935a4fef4fbda)
[Rotating an object to point towards the mouse](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86011/rotating-an-object-to-point-towards-the-mouse)

Comment: I can't speak for all, but I can say that for me, the single best thing that you can do to help me understand your problem is to create and post a decent [mcve] (please see link).

Comment: I sniped most of code and posted whole code

Comment: In the future, please don't do this. Please have mercy on us and remember that we're all volunteers. Instead create an honest to goodness  real [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();` returns the absolute mouse location. You need the mouse location relative to your game canvas. You can modify the `render` method in your `game` class as follows:

```
 Point mouseLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
 SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(mouseLocation, this);
 handler.render(g, mouseLocation);
```

This requires you to modify the method signatures of your rendering methods accordingly. This is only one way to pass the `mouseLocation` from your game canvas to your Player's rendering method.
Use the `mouseLocation` instead of `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();` in your Player's render method.

There are a few more things you have to change to place the player in the center of the canvas and make him rotate around his center:

- You should set the size of the game canvas instead of the size of the window(`JFrame`). Do this by calling `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));` on the game canvas and by calling `frame.pack()` before `frame.setVisible(true)`. This will ensure that your game canvas has exactly the size specified by `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT`.
- You could add two fields `refx` and `refy` to your `GameObject` class which describe the reference point of your `GameObject` (e.g. its center). You could then construct a new `Player` by calling `new Player(WIDTH/2-16, HEIGHT/2-16, 16, 16, ID.Player, handler)` where the player's initial position is at (`WIDTH`/2-16, `HEIGHT`/2-16) and its reference point is (16,16) - the center of the player when the player is represented by a 32x32 rectangle.
- In the Player's render method initialize the center you want to rotate around with `int centerX = Math.round(x + refx); int centerY = Math.round(y + refy);` where (x,y) is the position of the object you want to rotate and (refx, refy) the point you want to rotate around relative to the object's position (e.g. x = `WIDTH`/2-16, y = `HEIGTH`/2-16, refx = 16, refy = 16).

Comment: Still idk. I can't implement MouseMotionListener to game because I've got there running. Can u edit it and drop there more details please?

Comment: @EJskater I just edited my answer. I got rid of the `MouseMotionListener` using `SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen()` instead.

Comment: Look at images at end that I posted. Is it how it should work? If yes then what I have to change to be like on img. Btw ty very much

Comment: @EJskater The rotation seems to work now. Do you want to draw the image/rectangle so that center of canvas == center of image/rect and rotate it around that center?

Comment: Exactly that. (I want to know that(object can move but still is in center of canvas and different method where object moves and it wont be center)

Comment: @EJskater I just edited my answer accordingly.