# Rotate player towards mouse

Tags: java

I want my player rotate towards mouse. Here's the code calculating the angle:

```
float angle = (float) Math.atan2(MouseInput.getMousePos().y - transform.position.y + transform.size.y / 2,
                MouseInput.getMousePos().x - transform.position.x + transform.size.x / 2);

        angle = (float) (angle * (180 / Math.PI));

        if (angle < 0) {

            angle = 360 + angle;
        }

        transform.rotation = 180 + angle;
```

And getMousePos() method (it just returns mouse pos relative to window):

```
public static Vector2 getMousePos() {

        Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        return new Vector2(p.x - Game.w.getAccessToWindow(Acces.WINDOW_JFRAME_ACCES).getLocation().x,
                p.y - Game.w.getAccessToWindow(Acces.WINDOW_JFRAME_ACCES).getLocation().y);
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with this code? Player isn't rotating properly.

I tried following this article: https://gamefromscratch.com/gamedev-math-recipes-rotating-to-face-a-point/

Update:
I found this post: [Java 2d rotation in direction mouse point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911316/java-2d-rotation-in-direction-mouse-point)

Now I've updated my code to this:

```
int centerX = (int) (transform.size.x / 2);
        int centerY = (int) (transform.size.x / 2);
        int mouseX = (int) MouseInput.getMousePos().x;
        int mouseY = (int) MouseInput.getMousePos().y;
        double angle = Math.atan2(centerY - mouseY, centerX - mouseX) - Math.PI / 2;
        transform.rotation = angle;
```

But still something is off. Try this code for yourself. Maybe I did something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: What happens instead? Did you step through your code with a debugger already? Do you also realize that `angle` first is expressed in radians and `angle = (float) (angle * (180 / Math.PI));` converts it to degrees? However, `transform.rotation` might need an angle in radians again - we can't tell because we don't know what `transform` is and how you're using it.

Comment: Player sometimes isn't rotating towards mouse. Sometimes it is perfectly rotated and sometimes it off like 45 deg

Comment: @Thomas also transform is just Vector2(float, float), Vector2(float, float), float. Example Transform transform = new Transform(new Vector2(0,0), new Vector2(20,20), 40f);

Comment: Also I use java.awt.Graphics.rotate(rot, x, y). I think it uses radians as input.

Comment: "I think it uses radians as input." - that's exactly the problem. If `rot` in that case is just `transformation.rotation` then you're passing the angle in degrees to a method that expects radians. You need to either stick to one form or make sure you always know what unit the angle is expressed in and convert accordingly.